# Why doesn't this work?

Tags: trigonometry

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DZmF.jpg

I'm trying to find the sum of $\cos(\frac{\pi}{k}) + \cos(\frac{2\pi}{k}) + \cos(\frac{3\pi}{k}) + ... + \cos(\frac{n\pi}{k})$

I multiplied it by $2\sin(\frac{\pi}{k})$ and realised that terms sort of cancelled out. I got some formula for the sum but it did not work when I tested it and I dunno why not.

Thanks.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Comment: that is a nice method, and your answer is correct.

Comment: You could also multiply by $2\sin(\tfrac{\pi}{2k})$ to get neighboring terms to cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is correct. What you did is to lead the following :

$$2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)\sum_{i=1}^{n}\cos \left(\frac{i\pi}{k}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{k}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{(n+1)\pi}{k}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right).$$

However, note that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\cos \left(\frac{i\pi}{k}\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{k}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{(n+1)\pi}{k}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)}.$$
holds only when $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)\not =0$.